# ui-router: A route with no view template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to setup a route in `ui-router` that only has a controller? The purpose being that at a certain URL, the only thing I'd like to do is take action programatically, and not display anything in terms of a view. I've read through the docs, but I'm not sure if they offer a way to do this.

Yes, I have read this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state, but that is not quite what I am looking for.

For example, let's just say I have a basic body with view:

```
<body ui-view></body>
```

And some basic config:

```
// Routes
$stateProvider
  .state('myaction', {
    url: "/go/myaction",
    onEnter: function() {
      console.log('doing something');
    }
  });
```

When `/go/myaction` is visited, the view is blank. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: A plunker should make it easier to view the problem.

Comment: Have you tried that code? Does it work? If not, what goes wrong?

Comment: If you attempt to do that, then whatever your `ui-view` directive is on will load the template that you (haven't) specified, which therefore your view is blank.

Comment: Controllers are *only* for managing views. As mentioned below, they will not be instantiated if no template is specified. If you're just doing something programmatically, then `onEnter` is the correct thing to use.

Comment: Shouldn't a route always map to a view? Maybe you should execute your code based on an event.

Comment: @kontur That's why this is a *state* manager and not a route.  The docs talks about how the state manager may or may not include a route: AngularUI Router is a routing framework for AngularJS, which allows you to organize the parts of your interface into a state machine. Unlike the $route service in the Angular ngRoute module, which is organized around URL routes, UI-Router is organized around states, which may optionally have routes, as well as other behavior, attached.

Comment: Actually, yes! I redirected to a valid state WITH a veiw :) Just got clever about it. I posted the explicit code as an answer for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by redirecting the headless state I was taking programmatic action in, to a state WITH a view at the end of the headless state:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('myaction', {
    url: "/go/myaction",
    onEnter: function() {
      console.log('doing something');
    }
    controller: function($state) {
      $state.go('home');
    }
  });
```

Comment: It does not work in v0.2.13. Controller does not instantiated without template

Comment: ... at least for nested states.

Answer (score 10):

You can't have a controller without a view but you can use `onEnter` instead of a controller. If you don't want to change the current view when accessing this state you can define it as a child state:

```
$stateProvider

   // the parent state with a template
   .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
   })

   // child of the 'home' state with no view
   .state('home.action', {
      url: '/action',
      onEnter: function() {
         alert('Hi');
      },
   });
```

Now in `home.html` you can do something like this:

```
<a href ui-sref=".action">Greet me!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Warning: The controller will not be instantiated if template is not defined.

Why don't you use an empty string as a template to overcome this?

Comment: Because then whatever the `ui-view` directive is specified on, is blank.

Comment: This is no longer true. The controller is instantiated even without a view (my experience).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Use [absolute view names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names) to re-use the `<ui-view>` of another state.

**Take a look at this example:**

Users go to my app, but depending on them being authenticated or not, I want to send them to a public or private page. I use the `index` state purely to see if they're logged in or not, and then redirect them to `index.private` or `index.public`.

The child states make use of [absolute view names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names) to use the `<ui-view>` element that corresponds to the `index` state. This way, I don't need to make a second nested `<ui-view>`.

```
$stateProvider.state('index', {
  url: "/",
  controller: 'IndexCtrl'
}).state('index.private', {
  views: {
    "@": {
      templateUrl: 'private.html',
      controller: 'PrivateCtrl'
    }
  }
}).state('index.public', {
  views: {
    "@": {
      templateUrl: 'public.html',
      controller: 'PublicCtrl'
    }
  }
});
```

A small note on this example: I'm using the `@` shortcut here. Normally you would use `viewname@statename`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this was just to include a template (html file) that is blank.