# Is it possible for ui-router to not change view when going to another state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible for ui-router to not change content in ui-view when going to another state? I need some modal dialog to appear above old content but when state changed ui-view get's erased.

```
.state 'user.login',
    url: '/user/login'
    resolve:
        from: ($state) ->   $state.current.name
    onEnter: ['$state', 'ngDialog', 'Session', 'from', ($state, ngDialog, Session, from) ->
        Session.ready.finally ->
            if Session.logged_in then $state.go 'categories'
            else 
                ngDialog.open
                    template: '/assets/login.html'
                    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
                    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
                .closePromise.then (res)->
                    if from.name then $state.go from
                    else $state.go 'categories'
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171655/ui-router-a-route-with-no-view-template) is similar question but the solution from there does not work work for me:

```
controller: function($state) {
      $state.go('home');
    }
```

without template, state controller just does not instantiated. At least in nested states.

When I change this state not to be nested then it work almost like I want except that URL would changed back which is not good for me,

Comment: The most native solution would be to go with multi views on a parent state.

Comment: why can't you just open a dialog in same view?

Comment: @charlietfl because I need state to be changed so that url would also be changed and user can go to login page by typing it's state url.

Comment: I'm confused then since you stated you wanted dialog to open over existing content

Comment: @charlietfl right, I want state to be changed, url to be changed but content of `ui-view` to stay as it was (from previous state or empty if no such).

Comment: nothing preventing you using same template & controller in multiple states. One as dialog and other as a "page"